# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/serviceworker.js"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, service-worker, ruby-on-rails-6

Installed Rails `6.0.3`. Ran `rails new [app]`, started the server, loaded the homepage and the server logs are showing this routing error. Any ideas? Here's my routes file which I haven't touched.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: I think there must be other steps here you haven't listed.  Because basically that error means that serviceworker.js is included on some page somewhere and the file doesn't exist - common issue right?  But there is no mention of serviceworker.js in the Rails app - https://github.com/rails/rails/search?q=serviceworker.js&unscoped_q=serviceworker.js so I think you've missed a few steps in your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going into Chrome's Dev Tools > Application > Clear Storage fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the service-worker in the rails, please refer  to as follows 
https://github.com/rossta/serviceworker-rails